# How to display all results getting inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#

here is my code

```
foreach (string word in words)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select * from skills  where (skills  like '%"+word+"%')",con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

            }
```

Finally i want to display all the results into a gridview or some where (in each looping its getting different results). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're creating a new data table every loop iteration, so losing the previous contents. Other than this you don't say what errors you're getting with this code or what you've tried to do to display it already. This would help. I'll also state the obligatory 'you should be using SQL Parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks' here.

Comment: you can use `MERGE` of datatables . see this link:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx

Comment: losing the previous contents..that is the exact problem..i want to display all the results...need your comments

Comment: please see the updated answer.. hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like :-

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (string word in words)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select * from skills  where (skills  like '%"+word+"%')",con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt1);
                if (dt!= null)// to check if datatable is empty:-
                dt.Merge(dt1, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
                else
                dt=dt1.copy();// copy one datatable to another
                dt1.clear();
            }
```

// Finally bind the datatable with gridview :-

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: how can display in a grid view?

Comment: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'copy'

Comment: @user2068501 what Pranav said about copy() is just a pseudocode, said that it must be replaced by your code to copy the DataTable.

Comment: how can i opy one data table to another

Comment: haipranav facing one problem that....if i iam searching for key word 'java' its displaying those who have skills as java..if my next key word is 'a' it also will return the same result what i got for previous one so more than one same result is getting...hope you got where i am stucked...give me your valuable comments on this and suggest me some solutions for this if you have anything than this

Comment: it seems datatable is not getting clear, when you get the next time record.. so try to  clear the datatable . i have updated the answer ..try if this can help

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display it in gridView C# winform, just do:

```
gridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

A very rough architecture though.

EDIT 1:

Okay, I misread the requirement. Scan read is not good enough. Pranav's answer already is a working solution, I will just add some additional notes for it.

First, the performance will get very bad if you are doing `SELECT` statement in for. It will open-close connection everytime the SELECT hit. Second, from mssql point of view, where like '%word%' will get you trouble because it cannot be indexed. Furthermore, it will be better if you can get the right data so you can construct `where skill in('skill1', 'skill2', '..', '..')`, resulting faster performance and reducing requirement for for in DataTable.

If you still need to use %word%, then consider using temp table, and doing query in sql instead. Regularly, it should perform faster than doing for- SELECT.

Comment: But sir it will display only what we got as last result in looping..i am trying to write all the results..

Comment: Ok I misread the requirement. Use Pranav's answer instead. It is good.